# Is this the correct notation?

Tags: notation

$\left [ \left \{ 1,2,3,4 \right \}! \right]^{-1}$Is this the correct notation if one wanted to obtain the factorial for each number in a sequence and then take the sequence and inverse each number in it?

Comment: What's the $\mathbb{N}$ for? In mathematics it isn't customary to apply operations pointwise to a sequence like that. (Instead we apply operations pointwise to a function.)

Comment: Ah, I'm learning sequences and I still have to get the notation down, thanks! And I need to edit that N out.

Comment: Reminds me of [APL,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) a very clever (too clever) very compact (too compact) programming language. In principle if is OK, if $f$ is a function and $A$ is a subset of the domain, then $f(A)$ has a clear meaning. But not a good idea.

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Wikipedia :: Map (higher-order function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29)

Comment: Wow thanks! It is not customary to apply operations to sequences, as Qiaochu said. Is there anyway to write it so it is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just write $a_n=\frac 1{n!}$, or if the sequence were defined somewhere else as $b_n$, say $c_n=\frac 1{b_n!}$